# Xamarin.Forms Background/Foreground Service Best Practices?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms

I'm working on building an App with Xamarin.Forms that will periodically (re: every second) potentially do something, regardless of if the application is in the foreground or background.  Think something like a Timer/Clock.

I've found plenty of information on the Android side of things.  It looks like prior to 8, you can run it in a service -- and at 8 or later, you'll need to run it as a Foreground Service.

e.g.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services

From what I can tell, if I want to write any kind of controller to initialize this service (only if necessary in my client app), I'd have to add Mono.Android to the main shared library, which seems like the wrong thing to do, since the iOS version would ALSO have this dependency.

However, the iOS documentation is a little spotty when I search for it, as are best practices.  I'm not sure if the correct route is to do Backgrounding -- or if that'll close things down.

e.g.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/introduction-to-backgrounding-in-ios

It seems that Xamarin.Forms has come a LONG way with how things work in the past few years -- even 2016 to 2017 has a number of things changing.  The web is crowded with tons of different (and no longer valid) tutorials on all of this.

Right now, I have a singleton instance of a state-tracker that can be called to update every second (or other controls, i.e. skip forward one minute).

Are there any best practices for cross-platform foreground service development?  My best guess at this point is to publish Messaging events from that Controller, with specific code inside the main bodies of iOS and Android projects, which will then "know" how to create the appropriate services and then call the singleton instance of that state-tracker I mentioned before (which runs every second).

Are there any best practices or anything else that have something as simple as this published?  Periodic calls, while the service is "initialized," to run in the background and make calls against a state service to track/announce different states, as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Forms is ONLY user-interface cross platform development, and as Xamarin.Forms is based on .Net you can also use everything available in .Net for cross platform development. And that is as far as it goes out of the box. Some cross platform features not available in .Net are covered with official and unofficial plugins like Xamarin.Essentials.

To conclude unless there is a plugin for what you require (and I am not aware), you need to use the native Android and iOS functions. Also you are limited with their limitations.

There is no way to predictably run the app on iOS in the background. While there might be some workarounds like using the push notifications none of them are something that will work well in general situation.